# Is there a "Circuit Breaker" for Spring Boot Kafka client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, circuit-breaker

In case that Kafka server is (temporarily) down, my Spring Boot application `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` keeps trying to connect unsuccessfully, thus causing unnecessary traffic and messing the log files:

```plain-text
2021-11-10 14:45:30.265  WARN 24984 --- [onsumer-group-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-11-10 14:45:32.792  WARN 24984 --- [onsumer-group-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Bootstrap broker localhost:29092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-11-10 14:45:34.845  WARN 24984 --- [onsumer-group-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-11-10 14:45:34.845  WARN 24984 --- [onsumer-group-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Bootstrap broker localhost:29092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Is it possible to use something like a **circuit breaker** (an inspiration [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker) or [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html)), so the Spring Boot **Kafka client in case of a failure** (or even better a few consecutive failures) **slows down** the pace of its **connection attempts**, and returns to the normal pace only after the server is up again?

Is there already a ready-made config parameter, or any other solution?

I am aware of the [parameter](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_retry.backoff.ms) `reconnect.backoff.ms`, this is how I create the `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` bean:

```java
@Bean
public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, MyEvent> kafkaConsumer(KafkaProperties properties) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(properties.buildConsumerProperties());
    map.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "MyGroup");
    map.put(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 10_000L);
    final JsonDeserializer<DisplayCurrencyEvent> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.example.myapplication");

    return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(
            ReceiverOptions
                    .<String, MyEvent>create(map)
                    .withKeyDeserializer(new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new StringDeserializer()))
                    .withValueDeserializer(new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(jsonDeserializer))
                    .subscription(List.of("MyTopic")));
}
```

And still the consumer is trying to connect every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_retry.backoff.ms

> The base amount of time to wait before attempting to reconnect to a given host. This avoids repeatedly connecting to a host in a tight loop. This backoff applies to all connection attempts by the client to a broker.

and https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_reconnect.backoff.max.ms

> The maximum amount of time in milliseconds to wait when reconnecting to a broker that has repeatedly failed to connect. If provided, the backoff per host will increase exponentially for each consecutive connection failure, up to this maximum. After calculating the backoff increase, 20% random jitter is added to avoid connection storms.

and

Comment: I am aware of the `reconnect.backoff.ms` setting, I think I have used it correctly(?) - see my edited answer. However, still the consumer tries to connect every 3 seconds.

Comment: You need to set the `...max...` property as well.

Comment: To the same number, i.e. in my case 10_000 ms? I am not sure if I understand the description of the second parameter and its exact difference from the first one.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the two parameters? When will the first one apply? It seems that in the first "batch" of connection attempts, it's always like 3 seconds. Even from the log, it seems like they are two different sets of param values, `ConsumerConfig` is shown in the log multiple times with different values...

Comment: Sorry; I don't know kafka clients internals; try asking on their user mailing list: https://kafka.apache.org/contact