# How to configure Spring Boot Kafka client so it does not try to connect

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

This is related to [Is there a "Circuit Breaker" for Spring Boot Kafka client?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69914621/2886891), but I still think it's a *different* question :)

We need to configure Spring Boot Kafka client so it does not try to connect at all.

The use case is that in the test environment we do not have Kafka running but we still need to build the complete Spring Boot context, so making this bean conditional on profile would not work. We don't care if the been is not connected, but we need it to be existing.

The problem is that the unsuccessful attempts to connect take about 30-40 seconds and our tests are significantly slowed down.

Which of the [configuration parameters](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration) or which combination of them completely forbids the connection attempts, or at least forces the client to try it only once?

The code which retries to connect many times is this:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin.NewTopics topics() {
    return new KafkaAdmin.NewTopics(
            TopicBuilder.name("MyTopic").build()
    );
}
```

It repeatedly produces this warning:

```plain-text
WARN ... org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

The following code tries to connect only once:

```java
@Bean
public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, MyEvent> myConsumer(KafkaProperties properties) {
    return createConsumer(properties, "MyTopic", "MyConsumerGroup");
}

public <E> ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, E> createConsumer(KafkaProperties properties, String topic, String consumerGroup) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = configureKafkaProperties(properties, consumerGroup);

    return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(
        ReceiverOptions.<String, E>create(map)
            .subscription(List.of(topic)));
}
```

produces

```plain-text
WARN 7268 ... org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I have also tried setting the property
`spring.kafka.admin.fail-fast=true`
but this seem to have no effect at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just put ```kafka.enable=false``` in your application.properties?  If not ```autoStartup = "${auto.start:false}"``` should be your friend. Tho without a bit more information about the tests I am not 100% certain

Comment: My bad its not a standard setting. You would annotate your Config file with ```@ConditionalOnProperty("kafka.enabled")``` and then disable that for your tests

Comment: Then the second half of my comment should work for you.

Comment: ```autoStartup = "false"``` is a setting for your KafkaListener, which means it won't start the containers automatically, while still creating the Kafka Bean. My previous comment outlined how you could set it to be standard off. Tho if you want you can make it true on standard and then turn it off for your tests. As stated previously, this should fix your problem most likely tho with the limited information you provided I am not 100% certain


References:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot auto configures a `KafkaAdmin` which, by default, will connect to the broker to create any `NewTopic` beans. You can set its `autoCreate` property to false.

```java
    /**
     * Set to false to suppress auto creation of topics during context initialization.
     * @param autoCreate boolean flag to indicate creating topics or not during context initialization
     * @see #initialize()
     */
    public void setAutoCreate(boolean autoCreate) {
```

**EDIT**

To get a reference to the `KafkaAdmin`, simply add it as a parameter to any bean definition.

e.g.

```java
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin.NewTopics topics(KafkaAdmin admin) {
    admin.setAutoCreate(false);
    return new KafkaAdmin.NewTopics(
            TopicBuilder.name("MyTopic").build()
    );
}
```

Also see `KafkaAdmin.initialize()`.

```java
    /**
     * Call this method to check/add topics; this might be needed if the broker was not
     * available when the application context was initialized, and
     * {@link #setFatalIfBrokerNotAvailable(boolean) fatalIfBrokerNotAvailable} is false,
     * or {@link #setAutoCreate(boolean) autoCreate} was set to false.
     * @return true if successful.
     * @see #setFatalIfBrokerNotAvailable(boolean)
     * @see #setAutoCreate(boolean)
     */
    public final boolean initialize() {
```

When using `@KafkaListener` set `autoStartup = "false"` to prevent the consumers from starting when the context is initialized.

With reactor, just don't subscribe to the `Flux` returned by the `receive*()` methods (that's what triggers the consumer creation).

Comment: Thanks again, Gary, for your help. Especially for the part with "subscribe to the `Flux`" - this was especially tricky because the code is outside of my `KafkaConfiguration` class and I didn't realize that the connection attempt would occur *there*. Anyway, it would be nice if Kafka had some kind of a **single** `do-not-connect-mode` parameter exactly for this use case: "I need to instantiate all the beans, but I am not intending using them". It happens in unit tests quite often - you just need the complete Spring context built and reuse it for multiple unit tests to save test run time.

Comment: Please open a new feature request against `spring-kafka` - the `KafkaReceiver` has an overloaded static method `static <K, V> KafkaReceiver<K, V> create(ConsumerFactory factory, ReceiverOptions<K, V> options)` and tests could replace the standard consumer factory `@Bean` with one that creates a `MockConsumer` (or a mock factory if you don't need it at all). The template does not expose this overload. Also, you can use the `KafkaReceiver` directly - the template is a very lightweight wrapper for `KafkaReceiver`.